# GeoServer and Oracle Spatial synonym WFS-T Layer

Tags: geoserver, oracle-spatial, oracle-dbms, wfs-t

I have two schemas (A,B) in Oracle (19c) with one table in schema A where I want to write with WFS-T from the GeoServer.
The GeoServer is using the version 2.21.4 and corresponding OCI Driver.

The GeoServer needs to connect to schema B where I placed a synonym for the table in schema A.

Schema B has full rights in schema A on the table and I can select/insert/update the spatial data inside it from B. Schema B can see the table in USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA.

At the GeoServer interface I can only see features with a SQL view and query features from the layer.
Choosing oracle-NG to publish the layer and make it writable with WFS-T shows me the synonym and I can create the layer, but in the creation page it doesn't show me the feature types which you can normally see when creating a WFS-T layer on a table in the same schema.

Is it possible to do what I tried or is this a corner-case for the OCI driver?

Is there any other solution for the problem like connecting to the schema as another user like in the tutorial for PostgreSQL as open prepared statement?

I changed logging to geoserver_developer_logging but the output is not showing anything that gives me any clues.

```
21 038 12:38:49 INFO   [geoserver.filters] -IP "POST /geoserver/web/wicket/page?12-1.IBehaviorListener.0-publishedinfo-apply" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "my_url/geoserver/web/wicket/page?12" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" 
  Headers:
    host: myhost
    connection: keep-alive
    content-length: 1541
    sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    Wicket-FocusedElementId: id1d8
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
    Wicket-Ajax-BaseURL: wicket/page?12
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Wicket-Ajax: true
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
    Origin: origin
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
    referer: my_url/geoserver/web/wicket/page?12
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
    cookie: JSESSIONID=XXX; wtstp_eid=2166063782106098114; genesys.tracker.globalVisitID=43b0f12e-0885-4fe7-9ca3-cb8e703e195c; __ctmou_lej6ogei=cuid-1663051328311-ffpCYwmx.1663051325840; wteid_786452015021125=4166305133600084407; wteid_835283281675898=4166305133600511681; mmapi.p.srv=%22prodfracgeu03%22; mmapi.p.pd=%22ao0JSu1eWxtrV0qZTRJ0d3DGPJ6aVUAHh0U5L5Vt684%3D%7CCwAAAApDH4sIAAAAAAAEAGNhSFqxNMFLzL2TgTmtKJFRiIHRiaFJpymBjUFt78zvr4_f8jCpjt8QX3_LgwEIGIH4PxAw8JWXl-ul5-en56TqJefnsiwTA0lBAEgBDECFGF0B_gfWM2kAAAA%3D%22; utag_main=v_id:018335955cc800137f6fe21eaed40506f004c06701328$_sn:2$_se:1$_ss:1$_st:1668616351357$ses_id:1668614551357%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session; wt_nv=1; wteid_196380495960676=4166861455200552078; wteid_977515098753897=4166861455200450801; wt_rla=943593591056212%2C7%2C1681991592677%3B196380495960676%2C1%2C1668614552080%3B977515098753897%2C1%2C1668614552086%3B786452015021125%2C1%2C1668614552092%3B835283281675898%2C1%2C1668614552096; wt3_eid=%3B943593591056212%7C2166305652482118431%232168200051291071065%3B835283281675898%7C4166305133600511681 request-size: 1541 body:  bytes (binary content)

21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [geoserver.monitor] - Testing /web/wicket/page for monitor filtering
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.monitor] - /geoserver/web/wicket/page was filtered from monitoring
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 191 locking in mode READ
21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 191 got the lock in mode READ
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 191 locking in mode READ
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 191 releasing the lock in mode READ
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 191 locking in mode WRITE
21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 191 got the lock in mode WRITE
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.config] - Persisting feature type Layer_A
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69 to workspaces/Allgemein/schema/Layer_A/featuretype.xml
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76 to global.xml
21 038 12:38:49 INFO   [catalog.impl] - Layer Allgemein:Layer_A is missing the default style, assigning one automatically
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.config] - Persisting layer Layer_A
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71 to workspaces/Allgemein/schema/Layer_A/layer.xml
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76 to global.xml
21 038 12:38:49 TRACE  [gwc.layer] - Handling add event: LayerInfoImpl[Layer_A, resource:FeatureTypeInfoImpl[Layer_A]]
21 038 12:38:49 WARN   [gwc.layer] - Requested layer Layer_A has no geometry. Won't create TileLayer
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 191 locking in mode WRITE
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 191 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
21 038 12:38:49 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - IP "POST /geoserver/web/wicket/page?12-1.IBehaviorListener.0-publishedinfo-apply" took 125ms
21 038 12:38:49 DEBUG  [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file. You should be able to see all the requests that GeoServer is making to the server.